# ImportError when executing module under mod_python

Tags: python, import

I have a python project that is like this :

```
py/
   main.py
   __init__.py
   myapp/
           __init__.py
           my/
                __init__.py
                exam.py
           sub/
                __init__.py
                index.py
```

and my file contains :
main.py :

```
from myapp.sub.index import *
cd = myc()
cd.doit()
```

exam.py -->

```
class myclass():
  def hel(self):
     print 'Hello world'
```

index.py -->

```
from myapp.my.exam import myclass
class myc():
      def doit(self):
          mycc = myclass()  
          mycc.hel()
```

I use fedora and when I use command:

```
python main.py
```

prints `Hello world`, but when I want to start `main.py` in my browser with apache and mod_python this error appears:

```
File "/var/www/html/py/main.py", line 1, in <module>
  from myapp.sub.index import *

ImportError: No module named myapp.sub.index
```

Isn't relative import work in mod_python? what is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: How is this a relative import? You've used the complete module path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable isn't correctly set when executing the module under mod_python.

A workaround to the problem, using the directory structure described in the question, would be to add this to `main.py` file:

```
import sys, os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Please have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) for a nice explanation.